# XAML Datagrid set rowStyle if Value greater than

Tags: wpf, xaml, conditional-statements, setter, datatrigger

I've got a Datagrid with 3 columns.

Now i want to change the highlight of the row conditionally.
like: if the value in column 2 is greater than XX change row color to Red.

I've already tried something, but without success:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="18" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Steckzyklen}" Value="&lt; 20">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF4848"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Steckplatz"  Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="200"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Steckzyklen"  Binding="{Binding Steckzyklen}" Width="200"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Austauschdatum"  Binding="{Binding Austauschdatum}" Width="200"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

In this line: DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Steckzyklen}" Value="&lt 20"
I tried ti do it with the &lt but without succes.

Someone knows how to make it work? Preferably by only changing something in the XAML.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no "greater than" operator available in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Style as follows:

Create a new Converter:

```
    public class IsEqualOrLessThanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int intValue = (int)value;
            int compareToValue = Int32.Parse(parameter.ToString() ?? string.Empty);

            return intValue <= compareToValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And then:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Steckzyklen, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualOrLessThanConverter}, ConverterParameter=20}" Value="True">    
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFF4848"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. i implemented it but i get this error: The resource "IsEqualOrLessThanConverter" could not be resolved.

Comment: You need to add the resource to your xaml, if your xaml is Window so
    <Window.Resources>
        <IsEqualOrLessThanConverter x:Key="IsEqualOrLessThanConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>